# Simple Procedure for Printing the count of rows in a table without using COUNT operation ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure

Can anyone help me to create Simple Procedure for Printing the count of rows in a table without using COUNT operation in ORACLE ?

Comment: Why a procedure? Why "without using `COUNT`"? This seems like homework of some sort; and it's really terrible homework. If the best tool is the `COUNT` function, which it obviously is, and which is very basic and available in all flavors of SQL, why is anyone assigning you a homework problem to do something completely idiotic, like printing the count of rows **without** using COUNT? Can't they really find a realistic problem that would use the same skills or features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be looking for the `LOOP` in the procedure, considering that aggregate functions are not allowed..

Let's say I have an `account` table with 3 records in it.

> ```
> SQL> SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT;
>
>     ACC_NR       SUM_    CUST_ID
> ---------- ---------- ----------
>        500       3400        100
>        600       5000        101
>        700       5070        102
>
> SQL>
> ```

Now, creating the procedure:

> ```
> SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE COUNT_ACCOUNT (
>   2      P_OUT_COUNT OUT   NUMBER
>   3  ) AS
>   4  BEGIN
>   5      P_OUT_COUNT := 0;
>   6      FOR I IN (
>   7          SELECT
>   8              1 AS RW
>   9          FROM
>  10              ACCOUNT
>  11      ) LOOP
>  12          P_OUT_COUNT := P_OUT_COUNT + 1;
>  13      END LOOP;
>  14  END COUNT_ACCOUNT;
>  15  /
>
> Procedure created.
>
> SQL>
> ```

Executing the procedure to see the output:

> ```
> SQL> SET SERVEROUT ON
> SQL>
> SQL> DECLARE
>   2      CNT   NUMBER := 0;
>   3  BEGIN
>   4      COUNT_ACCOUNT(CNT);
>   5      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NUMBER OF RECORDS IN ACCOUNT TABLE: ' || CNT);
>   6  END;
>   7  /
> NUMBER OF RECORDS IN ACCOUNT TABLE: 3
>
> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
>
> SQL>
> ```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Now you can/may wrap the below with either

a procedure or a function with or without a return statement

```
DECLARE

CNT NUMBER;

BEGIN

SELECT MAX(ROWNUM) INTO CNT FROM TABLE_NAME;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NUMBER OF ROWS : '||CNT);

END;
```

Comment: thanks for the edit, 
sorry, i am not aware of the shouting reference part.

Comment: Here in this part of the world, we are used to having just individual letters and its collective meaning (not upper or lower or cursive or the emotions behind it or the mood of the reader). Just saying :-) 

However, if someone is offended and feel like down voting, just because of the way they appear, then that is pure case-ism

Comment: This site adheres to the conventions of written English (which are the conventions of many other languages written in the Roman alphabet). People will downvote answers (or questions) which are written wholly in upper case. That may seem like cultural imperialism but it remains a fact.